# Prometheus Alertmanager

Tags: docker

I'm attempting to get Prometheus sending alerts through alert manager with both in Docker containers. I have Prometheus alerting successfully but these alerts are not being passed to alert manager on the same host

Both containers spin up fine and configurations mount correctly from specified volumes which you can check using the WebUI. However when I trigger an alert and it's showing as Firing. No alerts appear in alertmanager

Here is the docker commands I use to start both containers

`docker run -d -p 9090:9090 --name=prom_server -v /prometheus-data/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml -v /prometheus-data/alert.rules:/etc/prometheus/alert.rules prom/prometheus -config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml -alertmanager.url=http://10.1.1.10:9093`

Here is the alertmanager docker instance

`docker run -d -p 9093:9093 --name=prom_alertmanager -v /prometheus-data/alertmanager.conf:/alertmanager.conf prom/alertmanager -config.file=/alertmanager.conf`

When I check this with docker inspect I can see the arguments being passed

```
[root@myserver]# docker inspect prom_server
...
"Cmd": [
                "-config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml",
                "-alertmanager.url=http://10.196.106.41:9093"
            ],
...
```

I've checked around and I can't see anywhere else you specify the alertmanager URL in the Prometheus server config. Yet no alerts are passed from one to another. I've no iptables running. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this one. I was thinking about the networking all wrong. Instead of trying to route through the host network, I should have been linking the 2 containers together using the --link parameter

`docker run -d -p 9090:9090 --name=prom_server --link prom_alertmanager -v /prometheus-data/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml -v /prometheus-data/alert.rules:/etc/prometheus/alert.rules prom/prometheus -alertmanager.url=http://promalertmanager:9093 -config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml`